# Override html output for a group of related node fields with Display Suite

Tags: display-suite

I am used to other php CMS, but new to Drupal, my first project, so I guess it's a beginner question.

I need to display several entity node fields (4 integers) with some text, in one table.

Obviously the template i would like to override is this one, in my particular case:

ds-1col--node-tour-full.tpl.php

which is an override of ds-1col.tpl.php, here is the code :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Display Suite 1 column template.
 */
?>
<<?php print $ds_content_wrapper; print $layout_attributes; ?> class="ds-1col    <?php print $classes;?> clearfix">

  <?php if (isset($title_suffix['contextual_links'])): ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix['contextual_links']); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php print $ds_content; ?>
</<?php print $ds_content_wrapper ?>>

<?php if (!empty($drupal_render_children)): ?>
  <?php print $drupal_render_children ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is this the good way to go ? I guess i have to modify the template because i cannot override the display of several fields together to group them in a table with a hook or preprocess function, that will be called for each field. May be i am wrong or there are easier way to go ?

Anyway, if it's the right path to follow, can someone point me out directions to go from the code in ds-1col.tpl.php to modify the output of that particular node type ?

Thanks